# Jenkins Pipeline is throwing Illegal Arugment exception

Tags: jenkins, parallel-processing, parameter-passing, jenkins-pipeline, illegalargumentexception

I am creating a Pipeline Parallel suite job which will trigger other standalone jobs with the passed parameters. But pipeline is throwing illegal argument exception after executing. Code used is am passing 4 parameters to a job created and placed under same folder.

Script Used:

```
node{
    environment_url=DeploymentEnvmt
    BrowserName=Browse          
parallel (
   { 
  build job: 'test_job', parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue',name: 'baseUrlFromDeploymentJob', value: "$environment_url"],[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'dynamicHubUrlTarget', value: "http://test.x.x.x/wd/hub"],[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'reDirectHubUrlVal', value: "yes"],[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'Browser', value: "$BrowserName"]] })
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected named arguments but got org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2@d78a0b
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.singleParam(DSL.java:542)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.parseArgs(DSL.java:530)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.parseArgs(DSL.java:470)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:183)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:153)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:108)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor493.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1213)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
```

Please help on resolving the Illegal Argument Exception error. What is need to be corrected withrespect to syntax

Answer (score 0):

It must be `Map<String, Closure>`, not a closure. [This](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/examples/#jobs-in-parallel) will be helpful for you.

```groovy
parallel(
    build(
        job: 'test_job',
        parameters:
            [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'baseUrlFromDeploymentJob', value: "$environment_url"],
                [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'dynamicHubUrlTarget', value: "http://test.x.x.x/wd/hub"],
                [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'reDirectHubUrlVal', value: "yes"],
                [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'Browser', value:
                    "$BrowserName"]
            ]
    )
)
```

Also you can simplify your `parameters` map:

```groovy
parallel(
  build(
      job: 'test_job',
      parameters: [
          string(name: 'baseUrlFromDeploymentJob', value: "$environment_url"),
          string(name: 'dynamicHubUrlTarget', value: "http://test.x.x.x/wd/hub"),
          string(name: 'reDirectHubUrlVal', value: "yes"),
          string(name: 'Browser', value: "$BrowserName")
    ]
  )
)
```

P.S. Thanks to @mkobit for correcting.

Comment: `parallel` takes in `Map<String, Closure>`, not a `List`.